# RequestError: Unable to load file in AJAX/DOJO

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo

I have hosted a text file named as hi.txt in the webapps folder of my tomcat server. I am able to access the url in browser but strangely my AJAX calls in the below code to display the file content is not working for the same link (//hostname:8080/dojo/hi.txt) .

I am getting an error message as **RequestError: Unable to load URL status: 0** . Can anyone suggest what can be the fix to this issue? I am using AJAX function in DOJO.

**P.S:** To see the error in the below code copy it in file_name.txt file and then save as file_name.html and open in IE or Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo: dojo/request/xhr</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/resources/style/style.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/resources/style/demo.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Demo: dojo/request/xhr</h1>
        <p>Click the button below to see dojo/request/xhr in action.</p>
        <div>
            <button id="textButton">Request Text File</button>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div id="resultDiv">
        </div>
        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.5/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script>
            require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"],
                function(dom, on, request){
                    // Results will be displayed in resultDiv
                    var resultDiv = dom.byId("resultDiv");

                    // Attach the onclick event handler to the textButton
                    on(dom.byId('textButton'), "click", function(evt){
                        // Request the text file
                        request.get("http://localhost:8080/dojo/hi.txt").then(
                            function(response){
                                // Display the text file content
                                resultDiv.innerHTML = "<pre>" + response + "</pre>";
                            },
                            function(error){
                                // Display the error returned
                                resultDiv.innerHTML = "<div class=\"error\">" + error + "<div>";
                            }
                        );
                    });
                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using different domains `ajax.googleapis.com, dojotoolkit.org and localhost:8080`. AJAX calls with different domains are not allowed. Try downloading the dojo source to your local tomcat server and just use 'request.get("dojo/hi.txt")' in your code which should work. If you want cross domain to work you need to use `JSONP` AJAX request in your code.

Comment: @frank Can you elaborate this part, I am not clear about the approach you suggested"Try downloading the dojo source to your local tomcat server and just use 'request.get("dojo/hi.txt")' in your code". I am a bit new to dojo configuration in tomcat so if you can explain me the steps a bit elaborately it will be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the dojo source from [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/). And place the files at the **same level** as the file **h1.txt** on the local tomcat server.
and then change the following line in your code.
from

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.5/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

to.

```
<script src="dojo/1.8.5/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Your directory structure on the server should look like this.

```
/index.html
/dojo/h1.txt
/dojo/1.8.5/dojo/<source files and subdirectories>
/dojo/1.8.5/dojox/<source files and subdirectories>
/dojo/1.8.5/dijit/<source files and subdirectories>
```